# Results of a PHP script not shown on the Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe

OK, so I have this fully working PHP script, available [HERE](http://www.sloparaglidingteam.si/zan/fai_pilot.php?p=4385) and the results should be shown in an iframe [HERE](https://sloparaglidingteam.si/en/national-team-2018/bgabersek-en/) under section "Best Results". But they are not.

However they are shown if I am viewing the page signed in as admin, but I frame is invisible to normal visitors. Why is that so? How can I solve that?

EDIT:
I am using Elementor to set up the page and Custom HTML widget element with the following code:

```
<iframe src="/zan/fai_pilot.php?p=4385" frameborder="0" width="100%"  scrolling="yes" height="440">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Show us the code how you are loading in the iframe

Comment: @Mike Good point, edited my OP.

Comment: Change `src=` to be the complete URL (ie: http://www.sloparaglidingteam.si/zan/fai_pilot.php?p=4385).

Comment: @Dave: Same result. :/

Answer (score 0):

When I load your outer page, i don't see an iframe tag in the Best Results section. So that leads me to believe if you're seeing it when logged in as admin, there is something in your Elementor config regarding roles/permissions you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: Don't use "Custom HTML" element from the Elementor, use "Text Editor" element instead.